# Double quotes issue in eval PHP

Tags: php, escaping, eval

Here is my code and I am getting an error like this.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ";' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in C:\wamp64\www\PHPQC\php\base\meditabmssql\med_page.php(1369) : eval()'d code on line 1.

Code:

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string wi"th my $name in it.';
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str;
?>
```

here is a reference(http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: just a hint: do *not* use eval unless you *exactly* know what you are doing. basically everything can be done without eval - without it's huge impacts on security and performance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should escape some characters:

```
<?php
$string = 'cup'; 
$name = 'coffee'; 
$str = 'This is a $string wi"th my $name in it.'; 
eval("\$str = \"\$str\";"); 
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't substitute `$string` and `$name` in `$str`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes that are inside `$str`. You can use `addslashes()` for this.

```
<?php
$string = 'cup'; 
$name = 'coffee'; 
$str = 'This is a $string wi"th my $name in it.'; 
$strslash = addslashes($str);
eval("\$str = \"$strslash\";"); 
echo $str;
?>
```